# How do I declare an array from a function globally?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to declare an array from the function globally so that my other functions can use it as well but I have no idea how to since I am using a csvtojson for converter which makes the whole thing very long and was wondering if this is the way to declare or no?

JS:

```
//require the csvtojson converter class 
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
 // create a new converter object
var converter = new Converter({});
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// call the fromFile function which takes in the path to your 
// csv file as well as a callback function
var JSarray = converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-
Management-New_2017.csv",function(err, result, callback){
if(err){
    console.log("An Error Has Occured");
    console.log(err);  
} 
// the result of the conversion
console.log(result);
result.toArray(function(err,doc){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('ohhhhh');
    return callback(null, doc);
}
});
```

`var array=[JSarray(function(err,doc)]` This is how I declare the array.
My array is doc and so I can return callback but how should I get the array considering I have `converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-
    Management-New_2017.csv"` which is too long so do I omit it when declaring the array or am I doing it wrong ? Thanks.

**Update**
 Just wanted to clarify if I did it correctly.

```
var JSarray = converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-M 
anagement-New_2017.csv",function(err, result, callback){
// if an error has occured then handle it
if(err){
    console.log("An Error Has Occured");
    console.log(err);  
} 
// the result of the conversion
console.log(result);
result.toArray(function(err,doc){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('ohhhhh');
    return callback(null, doc);
    var myArray= doc;
    GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray = myArray;
});
});
```

Is this correct following your answer in declaring it globally?

Comment: Global vars are bad practice.

Comment: Change to `var myArray= doc; GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray = myArray; return callback(null, doc);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array global inside of a function by assigning it to the window object.

```
function myFunction() {
    var myArray = new Array();
    window.GlobalMyArray = myArray;
}
```

Once it is set you can use `GlobalMyArray` from anywhere.

Using Node.Js you can use global

```
function myFunction() {
    var myArray = new Array();
     GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray = myArray;
}
```

You can now access the array globally using `GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray`

In which case it is very useful to do:

```
GLOBAL.window = GLOBAL
```

Like in the web browser.

Comment: If it's node.js (which is probable since it uses `require()`) it does not have a `window` object

Comment: Yeah, didn't catch that. There is require in web based javascript but its not used like that and the fact a local .csv file is being loaded. ;(

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Hi thanks for your answer. Wanted to clarify if I did 
 it correctly. I updated my question with your answer.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I still get not defined `myArray`

Comment: You have to access it with `GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray`. If you want to use my `myArray` then assign  `GLOBAL.myArray = myArray`;

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Sorry I am a little confused but your answer wrote `GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray = myArray` but you are saying assign `GLOBAL.myArray = myArray` so what do you mean?

Comment: In your update your wrote `GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray = myArray;' so myArray is a local variable. It will go out of scope when the function exists. So you need to use `GlobalMyArray` outside of the function to access the array.

Comment: Also `return callback(null, doc);` is causing your function to exit before you assign `GLOBAL.GlobalMyArray`

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins if I want to use this array outside of the scope it is declared in, I have to write `GlobalMyArray = myArray` in the other function to use it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148373/discussion-between-alexander-higgins-and-ong-kong-tat).

Comment: What is the conclusion here, guys @AlexanderHiggins. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined"

Answer (score 3):

global variables are not considered good programming practice.

Though you can create a *global object module* and reference this modules in all other modules in your project and play with exposed properties from it.

A simple example to achieve this is as following in node.js:

Create module **GlobalArray**. This module will expose a singleton object of the class it defines. The constructor of this class creates member variable. This class now expose the member variable using methods such as **Add**, **Get**. The instance of this class is exported from the module.

```
// File: GlobalArray.js

class GlobalArray { 
    constructor(){
        this.array = [];
    }
    Add(item) {
        this.array.push(item);
    }
    Get(){
        return this.array;
    }
}

let globalArray = new GlobalArray();
module.exports = globalArray;
```

Module for the class which add data to **Global Array** can be created as following:

```
// File: Add.js

const globalArray = require("./GlobalArray");

class Add { 
    AddToGlobalArray(){
        globalArray.Add("1");
        globalArray.Add("2");
        globalArray.Add("3");
        globalArray.Add("4");
        globalArray.Add("5");
    }
}

module.exports = Add;
```

Module for the class which print data from **Global Array** can be created as following:

```
// File: Print.js

const globalArray = require("./GlobalArray");

class Print {   
    PrintGlobalArray(){
        let array = globalArray.Get();
        for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            console.log(array[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Print;
```

Both **Add** and **Print** modules used statement `const globalArray = require("./GlobalArray")` to reference the **Global Array**.

Now, we can use **Add** and **Print** modules by referencing them in *index.js* to add and print data respectively using the **Global Array**.

```
// File: index.js

const Add = require("./Add");
const Print = require("./Print");

// Creating object of Add module to add data to global array
let addObject = new Add();
addObject.AddToGlobalArray();

// Creating object of Print module to print data from global array
let printObject = new Print();
printObject.PrintGlobalArray();
```

After executing *index.js*, it renders the following output:

```
>node index.js

1

2

3

4

5
```